# How do I host a Microsoft Office document inside a Winforms application?

Tags: .net, winforms, ms-office

Anyone that can recommend an Word, Excel and PowerPoint viewer (no editing), that can be used as a component in Winforms?

The viewer must support Office 2003, 2007 and 2010.

The target is .NET 4.0.

A free one is preferred ;-) But if its commercial its ok.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A quick search reveals quite a few - take your pick.

Comment: @ChrisF: What is the search term you used?

Comment: @Robert - http://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1GPCK_enGB369GB369&aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=microsoft+office+viewer+component - but I have to admit I didn't follow many of the links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally your best approach to this is to have your users obtain the appropriate read-only viewers from Microsoft.

[Word Viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=3657ce88-7cfa-457a-9aec-f4f827f20cac&displaylang=en)

[Excel Viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=1cd6acf9-ce06-4e1c-8dcf-f33f669dbc3a&displaylang=en)

[PowerPoint Viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=048dc840-14e1-467d-8dca-19d2a8fd7485&displaylang=en)

This is how the vast majority of document management systems work; they rely on the computer's file associations to target various readers.  So all you have to do is provide a link.

Comment: The client specifically wants to view the files in the WinForms application.

Comment: @marcus: As far as I know there's no way to do this well.  The Word viewer has a browser plugin I believe, so in theory you could host a webbrowser control, but it's not a pretty solution.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: But it requires MS Office installed

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to use the WebBrowser control in WinForms in combination with [Google Docs Viewer](http://docs.google.com/viewer)?