# PowerPoint Application as a Child

Tags: vsto, powerpoint, mdichild

I wanna know how to have a MDI Parent Form, which has some MDI Child forms and have the PowerPoint as a child too.
How can I do it? Is possible?
Ty in advance.

Comment: I doubt that that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [PowerPointViewer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13#overview) discussed over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259369/embed-powerpoint-viewer-in-c-sharp-win-form) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147872/how-do-i-host-a-microsoft-office-document-inside-a-winforms-application)